# how to identify the java version in which the code is written?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Let's say a banking application was developed in Java EE. And we are the new people working on that application now, not sure about the version of the Java EE used to develop that application.

How can we identify the version of Core Java/Java EE in which that project was developed?

Comment: They for sure would use an IDE, and for Java to be executed, they would have written some tests I believe (I hope more so). So they would actually know which java version they are dealing with

Comment: It depends on the artifact you have at hand. If you have the source projects, you can see the dependencies. If you have the binaries, then you can look at the manifest in jar files to see at least the JDK that built it. For JEE components, you can look at deployment descriptors (`web.xml`, `application.xml` will typically declare the version of the specification in top-level elements).

Answer (score 9):

> How can we identify the version of Core Java/Java EE in which that project was developed?

(Note that "developed for" and "runs on" are different questions.  I am answering the former ... which is what was asked.)

There is no 100% reliable way to do it.

- If the project is built using Maven or Gradle, the project's declared dependencies (in the build files) will list specific versions of the Java EE APIs, and (typically) specific Java source and target version.
- There probably be similar clues in an Ant build file, though in the case of dependencies you will be relying on clues in the pathnames of classpath entries ... which may not be there.
- For Java EE, there may be clues in the namespace URLs used the XML files; e.g. `web.xml`, `application.xml`.
- If the previous don't help, then you could test compile the codebase with various JDKs and against various Java EE APIs.  That should narrow down the range of versions that the codebase is *compatible* with.
- If you have existing `.class` files, then `javap` can tell you the target bytecode version that was used when building; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802542/139985).  However, this is not a reliable indicator, because it doesn't tell you what version of Java the codebase was *developed* for.

---

If you want to find out which version or versions of Java a project is actually compatible with or actually runs on, the only way to find out *for sure* is to test it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know which version of Java was used to compile the class, you can use `javap`, available in the JRE and JDK. It reads your class bytecode and tells you the version.

`javap -v out/com/kineolyan/tzio/diffs/Main.class` gives you:

```
Classfile /mnt/Grishka/Projets/project-tz-io/out/com/kineolyan/tzio/diffs/Main.class
  Last modified 9 oct. 2018; size 1806 bytes
  MD5 checksum 26b264396d74f1a68032bf5cd17aab09
final class com.kineolyan.tzio.diffs.Main
  minor version: 0
  major version: 53
  flags: (0x0030) ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
  ....
```

See [this page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Java_class_file#/General_layout) to match major and minor versions to standard names. For example, 53.0 is Java9.

Answer (score 5):

### To check the java version of a project (if build using maven)

1. go to  pom.xml
2. check **properties**
3. java.version

the code look like this

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <start-class>org.la.ecom.portal.teacher.EcommercePortalTeacherApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: I don't see this in POM.xml anymore. Has it been removed now (2022)?

Answer (score 2):

To check the java compatible version of a project built by **Gradle**

Go to `build.gradle` file and search for:

```
sourceCompatibility = '{version}'
```